# What do sigma confidence levels mean in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

My level of understanding of Particle Physics is elementary.

Suppose say I have conducted an experiment (maybe a poll) with a sample size of $n$, then I can calculate the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$ from the data. Once I have this, I can calculate the confidence interval for some confidence level. For example, if I'm interested in a confidence level of 95%, this corresponds to a z-value of 1.96 and I can calculate the confidence interval using $t = z \cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $z = \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)$, with $\Phi$ as the CDF of normal distribution (and in this case we have $\alpha = 0.95$). **Now I can report my result as $\mu \pm t$ with a confindence level of 95%**.

Let's now look at particle physics. When a particular result is reported like $\mu \pm t$ with a confindence level of $5\sigma$, is this same as what we have in the pervious case? If that's the case, can we not always report the result with a higher confidence level for some fixed sample size? Then what is the significance of having $5\sigma$ required for a significant experiment?

I am aware that the confidence level calculations are not as straightforward as I have described them here. All I am trying to understand is how it fits with the usual "confidence interval/confidence level" used in statistics.

Comment: Isn't this just a measure of the signal-to-noise ratio?  That is, a 5$\sigma$ measurement implies that the signal is so far above the noise as to remove almost all doubt of it being artificial, right?